# How and why do void methods become void in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, function, methods

I'm new to stack overflow and am a noob at programming. I've stumbled across void methods; I understand what they are and what they mean/do but I feel like they don't quite click with me well, yet.

```
t = ['d', 'c', 'e', 'b', 'a']
t = t.sort()
```

This code above, for example, wouldn't work (this is from freeCodeCamp's "Python for Everybody" textbook/trinket thing).

I did Google and I know about the return and that it's probably what makes a method void. I guess I know the how but want to know why, which would probably satisfy me.

Comment: `void` just means the function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

functions in python don't return void, it's a common practice that functions which modify their inputs return `None` which is a python object, note the following function.

```py
def zero_first_lement(some_list):
    some_list[0] = 0
    return None
 
t = ['d', 'c', 'e', 'b', 'a']
t = zero_first_lement(t)
```

running the above function would cause `t` to be `None`.

python functions that have no return also return `None` because they "must return something", omitting the `return None` line makes no difference.

python is an interpreted language, the interpreter doesn't know what the value of `t` will become from `t = zero_first_lement(t)` until the function actually runs, and if the function doesn't explicitly return something then `t` will be assigned `None`.

Comment: Thank you! So the function returns 'None' because they directly modify the input, is that right? Also, when I try to assign the void function to a variable, the variable is looking for a returned value (if that makes sense), is that why it returns 'None' because that's the value being returned?

Comment: @Dreaj yes, exactly, `t.sort()` is a class method, so it takes `t` as its first argument (look into classes) so it falls under "it modifies its inputs" umbrella.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's much clearer now.